# Swaping two number in Nodejs dont know why getting runtime error

Tags: node.js, node-modules, swap

I'm trying to write a code swapping two numbers in nodejs but I'm getting runtime error.
When I run a second time when the file was saved already then again getting same error. I think this is related to closing the file somehow. Has anyone any ideas? My code is as follows -

```js
function swap(num1 , num2){             
    let temp = num1;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = temp;
    return; 
}

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('ascii');

var input_stdin = "";
var input_stdin_array = "";
var input_currentline = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', function (data) {
    input_stdin += data;
});

process.stdin.on('end', function () {
    input_stdin_array = input_stdin.split("\n");
    main();    
});

function readLine() {
    return input_stdin_array[input_currentline++];
}

function main() {
    let t = parseInt(readLine());
    while(t-->0){
        const arr = readLine().replace(/\s+$/g, '').split(' ');
        var num1 = (Number)(arr[0]);
        var num2 = (Number)(arr[1]);
        var res = swap(num1 , num2) ; 
        console.log(res[0] , res[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: PLEASE REMEMBER TO COPY/PASTE THE ERROR MESSAGE!

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning from your `swap` function, so `res` == `undefined`.

```js
function swap(num1, num2) {
  return [num2, num1];
}
```

This should fix that

Comment: Good catch!  Minor quibble: He's "returning" ... but he's not returning a *value* from the function.  And the OP should be reminded to EXPLICITLY STATE THE ERROR MESSAGE.  A vague "getting runtime error" is unhelpful...